# Eclipse subsersive - delete a file but keep it locally

Tags: eclipse

my question is in the title. How can I delete a file from the repository but 
keeping it locally ? In other words, an eclipse subsersive equivalent to the 
"svn --keep-local" command line

When I right-click on my file, the only Delete item I can found is even 
not in the TEAM menu but in the general file menu. By deleting it, it will be removed from the repository at the next commit BUT also locally.

any idea ?

thank you very much

Eric Pellegrini

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the **SVN Repository Exploring** perspective.
2. Using either the **SVN Repositories** or **SVN Repository Browser** view, navigate to the file you want to delete.
3. Right-click and select **Delete...**

This will delete the file in the repository, but will keep the local copy intact.

Comment: And how do you go on from here? Next commit you will have a conflict, how do you solve it and still keep the local file?

Comment: You probably want to add it to your svn ignore file.